# Flutter: how to choose which Android project to run?

Tags: flutter

I have a Flutter project that is also a **module** project. That means:

- I have a "android" folder.
- I also have a ".android" folder.

This causes some issues when I try to build or run the project:

- When I run it, the flutter framework install the ".android" (generated) app into the phone.
- When I build (release) it generates an apk based on the "android" folder.

How do I specify which folder I want the flutter's to work with?

---

A problem that happend to me:

I added shared_preferences to my **pubspec.yaml**.
Running the app by intellij was working fine and nothing wrong was happening, but when I run a `flutter build apk` and then a `flutter install`, the app in the Android device was throwing a "MissingPluginException".

Then I checked the `GeneratedPluginRegistrant` file from the "android" folder and it was completely out of date.

To fix it I had to comment the pubscpec.yaml entire "module" property (with its *androidPackage* and *iosBundleIdentifier* sub-properties). By doing this, Flutter started to generate properly all the files for the "android" folder.

Comment: The question is not very clear. You need to run `lib/main.dart`. "How do I specify which folder I want the flutter's to work with?" There is nothing to specify. "causes some issues" please provide more details.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I updated the question with a problem that happend to me.

Comment: I missed that you try to add Flutter to an existing native app. Sorry, can't help you with that.

Comment: Can you upvote my question then?

Comment: Also reported in https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23572